# Matrix vector batch multiplication with variable batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply a set of matrices with a set of vectors in tensorflow. I have two tensors with shapes [k,n,n] and [k,n], respectively. If I set the k in the network, then can do the pairwise dot as:

```
final =  tf.einsum("kji,ki->kj", M, V)
```

However the einsum() does not work with tensors of  dynamic shape(variable batch size):

> File "...\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\special_math_ops.py", >line 207, in einsum
>      axes_to_sum)
>
> File "...\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\special_math_ops.py", >line 252, in _einsum_reduction
>      if len(t0_axis_labels) != len(t0.get_shape()):
>
> File "...\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", >line 575, in **len**
>      raise ValueError("Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank.")
>
> ValueError: Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank.

Any Idea how to approach the problem differently?
Note, that in np notation I need to achieve the following:
for c with shape [k, n]

```
c = np.zeros([k,n])
c[i,:] = np.dot(M[i,:,:],V[i,:])
```

TF version 1.8